# How to check the version of NCCL

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, horovod

I remotely access High-performance computing nodes. I am not sure about NVIDIA Collective Communications Library (NCCL) is installed in my directory or not. Is there any way to check whether the NCCL is installed or not?

Comment: did you try `nvcc --version`?

Comment: you can do `python -c "import torch;print(torch.cuda.nccl.version())"` with pytorch. I wish I new the terminal command without pytorch.

Comment: i tried `print(torch.cuda.nccl.version())`, it throws me this error: 
`AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute '_nccl_version'`

Answer (score 19):

You can try

```
locate nccl| grep "libnccl.so" | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/^.*\.so\.//'
```

or if you use PyTorch:

```
python -c "import torch;print(torch.cuda.nccl.version())"
```

Check it this link [Command Cheatsheet: Checking Versions of Installed Software / Libraries / Tools for Deep Learning on Ubuntu](https://tech.amikelive.com/node-841/command-cheatsheet-checking-versions-of-installed-software-libraries-tools-for-deep-learning-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

For containers, where no `locate` is available sometimes, one might replace it with `ldconfig -v`:

```
ldconfig -v | grep "libnccl.so" | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/^.*\.so\.//'
```

Comment: When I enter `locate nccl| grep "libnccl.so" | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/^.*\.so\.//'1, it show nothing.

Comment: torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined symbol: ncclCommRegister

Answer (score -4):

You can usually do this in the command line:

```
nvcc --version
```

you might have to run:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

too.

---

As the other answerer mentioned, you can do:

```
torch.cuda.nccl.version()
```

in pytorch. Copy paste this into your terminal:

```
python -c "import torch;print(torch.cuda.nccl.version())"
```

I am sure there is something like that in tensorflow.

Comment: NVCC is a general CUDA C++ compiler. It doesn't report NCCL (communications library) version. The first part of the answer is wrong.

Comment: i tried `print(torch.cuda.nccl.version())`, it throws me this error: 
`AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute '_nccl_version'`